# Back button pressed on parent activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

in action bar when back button is pressed how do I know in the previous activity that back button was pressed , `onCreate()` does not get called when back button is pressed

I know from the code below that on current activity that back button was pressed but I need to know on previous activity that back button was pressed

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        this.finish();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to know that?  Its not generally something you need to know.  What are you going to do differently if your activity was returned to via the back button than via some other means?

Comment: need to reload the ListView to get updated items from db

Comment: You should do that every time in onResume.  That way if your user is away for any reason (such as minimizing the app) you update his display.

Answer (score 0):

You can navigate between activities using [`registerForActivityResult()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/result/ActivityResultCaller#registerForActivityResult(androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContract%3CI,O%3E,androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultCallback%3CO%3E)) API, and put some extra data in the returned intent that can show you from where it came from.

##### At source activity:

```
ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> launcher = registerForActivityResult(
        new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
        result -> {
            if (result.getResultCode() == AppCompatActivity.RESULT_OK) {
                if (result.getData() != null) {
                    String data = result.getData().getStringExtra("ACTIVITY_FROM");
                    if (data != null)
                        switch (data) {
                            case "ACTIVITY2":
                                // Returned from Activity2
                                Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: Returned from Activity2");
                                break;
                            case "ACTIVITY3":
                                // Returned from Activity3
                                Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: Returned from Activity3");
                                break;
                        }
                }
            }
        }
);

// Go to Activity 2:
auncher.launch(new Intent(this, Activity2.class));
```

##### At the destination activity:

Then put the data when you need to return back from Activity2:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        setIntent();
        this.finish();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}   

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    setIntent();
    finish();
    super.onBackPressed();
}

private void setIntent() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("ACTIVITY_FROM", "ACTIVITY2");
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);  
}
```